# Firebase getDownloadURL Not working Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Really need help guys, Here is my Firebase Storage Security Rule

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/shoppinglist-XXXX.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Java Code to get a URL Link

```
storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
   pathRef = storageRef.child("MyBook.pdf");

    storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Log.d(tag, "MyDownloadLink:  " + uri);
        }
    });
```

Here is my Error:

```
     StorageException has occurred.
     User does not have permission to access this object.
{  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Developer credentials required."  }}
                                                                            java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Developer credentials required."  }}
```

Can Someone Please Help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably meant to download from `pathRef`, not `storageRef`.  Downloading from the root of the storage tree is not permitted.

Comment: It worked! thank you, i was using storageRef when I should have been using pathRef , Thank you Qbix.